# Only primitive types are supported in this context

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I have the following extract of code and I get the above error. This is a really simple query and of course works perfectly in SQL. What am I missing?

```
public IEnumerable<PAYSHIST> GetPayrollCriteria(string COID, IEnumerable<ASITE> sites)
{
    var recs = from p in _entities.PAYSHISTs
               join a in sites on p.SITE_CODE equals (a.SALES_ACC + a.SITE_NUMBER.ToString("000"))
               select p;
    return recs;
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of string COID?

Answer (score 1):

You cant join an in memory collection with a database table. Try writing the query as follows instead using `Contains`:

```
var recs = from p in _entities.PAYSHISTs
           where sites.Select(a => a.SALES_ACC + a.SITE_NUMBER.ToString("000"))
                 .Contains(p.SITE_CODE)
           select p;
```

Comment: It's not sorry. Linq to Entities.

Comment: It doesn't work, there is no such property as .Select on my sites object (which is an IEnumerable).

Comment: @MattB Updated the answer, but surely there is a [Select on IEnumerable<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891.aspx)

Comment: I'll check again but it certainly didn't let me compile when I looked before.

Comment: Probably need .Where or .Single instead.